# how to enable vertical sync in opengl?

Tags: opengl, vsync, vertical-sync

How do you enable vertical sync?

Is it something simple like `glEnable(GL_VSYNC)`? (though there's no such thing as GL_VSYNC or anything like it in the options that glEnable accepts).

or is there no standard way to do this in opengl?

Answer (score 49):

On Windows there is OpenGL extension method `wglSwapIntervalEXT`.
From the post by b2b3 http://www.gamedev.net/community/forums/topic.asp?topic_id=360862:

> If you are working on Windows you have to use extensions to use
>   `wglSwapIntervalExt` function. It is
>   defined in wglext.h. You will also want to
>   download glext.h file.
>   In wglext file all entry points for Windows specific extensions are
>   declared. All such functions start
>   with prefix wgl.
>   To get more info about all published extensions you can look into
>   OpenGL Extension Registry.
>
> `wglSwapIntervalEXT` is from `WGL_EXT_swap_control` extension. It
>   lets you specify minimum number of
>   frames before each buffer swap.
>   Usually it is used for vertical
>   synchronization (if you set swap
>   interval to 1). More info about whole
>   extension can be found here.
>   Before using this function you need query whether you card has
>   support for `WGL_EXT_swap_control` and
>   then obtain pointer to the function
>   using `wglGetProcAddress` function.
>
> To test for support of given extension you can use function like this:

```cpp
#include <windows.h>
#include "wglext.h"

bool WGLExtensionSupported(const char *extension_name)
{
    // this is pointer to function which returns pointer to string with list of all wgl extensions
    PFNWGLGETEXTENSIONSSTRINGEXTPROC _wglGetExtensionsStringEXT = NULL;

    // determine pointer to wglGetExtensionsStringEXT function
    _wglGetExtensionsStringEXT = (PFNWGLGETEXTENSIONSSTRINGEXTPROC) wglGetProcAddress("wglGetExtensionsStringEXT");

    if (strstr(_wglGetExtensionsStringEXT(), extension_name) == NULL)
    {
        // string was not found
        return false;
    }

    // extension is supported
    return true;
}
```

> To initialize your function pointers you need to:

```cpp
PFNWGLSWAPINTERVALEXTPROC       wglSwapIntervalEXT = NULL;
PFNWGLGETSWAPINTERVALEXTPROC    wglGetSwapIntervalEXT = NULL;

if (WGLExtensionSupported("WGL_EXT_swap_control"))
{
    // Extension is supported, init pointers.
    wglSwapIntervalEXT = (PFNWGLSWAPINTERVALEXTPROC) wglGetProcAddress("wglSwapIntervalEXT");

    // this is another function from WGL_EXT_swap_control extension
    wglGetSwapIntervalEXT = (PFNWGLGETSWAPINTERVALEXTPROC) wglGetProcAddress("wglGetSwapIntervalEXT");
}
```

> Then you can use these pointers as any other pointer to function. To enable vync you can call `wglSwapIntervalEXT(1)`, to disable it you call `wglSwapIntervalEXT(0)`.
>
> To get current swap interval you need to call `wglGetSwapIntervalEXT()`.

Comment: In your first code snippet if (strstr(_wglGetExtensionsString(), extension_name) == NULL) should read if (strstr(_wglGetExtensionsStringEXT(), extension_name) == NULL) -- But thanks, this helped me!!!

Comment: Also I used wglGetProcAddress instead of LogGetProcAddress

Comment: That is not an extension to OpenGL, but rather to WGL (the Microsoft Windows window system API for OpenGL). Buffer swapping is by its very nature a window system specific operation. As far as GL is concerned it just draws to a front/back left/right buffer or some arbitrary FBO. The window system is the only thing with enough knowledge of the underlying host system to synchronize the presentation of drawn buffers to some event (in this case the monitor's vertical retrace).

Answer (score 9):

**WGL** case is described in the [answer by eugensk00](https://stackoverflow.com/a/589232/673852).

For **CGL** (MacOSX) see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10881400/673852) to another SO question.

For **EGL** there's [eglSwapInterval()](https://www.khronos.org/registry/egl/sdk/docs/man/html/eglSwapInterval.xhtml) function, but apparently (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11971947/xlib-egl-how-to-get-vsync-swapinterval-on-eglswapbuffers) and [this](https://community.arm.com/thread/4815)) it doesn't guarantee tearing-free result — only waits given period (maybe it's just due to broken drivers).

For **GLX** (Linux with X11 etc.) there are at least 3 similar extensions for this, with varying degree of functionality. OpenGL wiki currently lists only one, which is unsupported by Mesa <= 10.5.9 (and maybe higher). Here's a list from most feature-complete extension (listed in OpenGL wiki) to the least:

1. [GLX_EXT_swap_control](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/EXT/swap_control.txt)

   - Set swap interval per-drawable per-display: `glXSwapIntervalEXT(dpy, drawable, interval)`
   - Get current swap interval: `glXQueryDrawable(dpy, drawable, GLX_SWAP_INTERVAL_EXT, &interval)`
   - Get maximum swap interval: `glXQueryDrawable(dpy, drawable, GLX_MAX_SWAP_INTERVAL_EXT, &maxInterval)`
   - Disable Vsync: set `interval` to 0
2. [GLX_MESA_swap_control](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/MESA/GLX_MESA_swap_control.txt)

   - Set swap interval per-context: `glXSwapIntervalMESA(interval)`
   - Get current swap interval: `glXGetSwapIntervalMESA()`
   - Get maximum swap interval: *unsupported*
   - Disable Vsync: set `interval` to 0
3. [GLX_SGI_swap_control](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/SGI/GLX_SGI_swap_control.txt)

   - Set swap interval: `glXSwapIntervalSGI(interval)`.
   - Get current swap interval: *unsupported*
   - Get maximum swap interval: *unsupported*
   - Disable Vsync: *unsupported* (`interval==0` is an error)

For adaptive Vsync see [OpenGL wiki](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Swap_Interval#Adaptive_Vsync).

Answer (score 5):

```
((BOOL(WINAPI*)(int))wglGetProcAddress("wglSwapIntervalEXT"))(1);
```

https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Swap_Interval

> "wglSwapIntervalEXT(1) is used to enable vsync; wglSwapIntervalEXT(0) to disable vsync."
>
> "A swap interval of 1 tells the GPU to wait for one v-blank before swapping the front and back buffers. A swap interval of 0 specifies that the GPU should never wait for v-blanks"

---

Alternatively: (wgl function typedefs are in `#include <GL/wglext.h>`)

```
((PFNWGLSWAPINTERVALEXTPROC)wglGetProcAddress("wglSwapIntervalEXT"))(1);
```

```
PFNWGLSWAPINTERVALEXTPROC wglSwapIntervalEXT = (PFNWGLSWAPINTERVALEXTPROC)wglGetProcAddress("wglSwapIntervalEXT");
wglSwapIntervalEXT(1);
```

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged. Please add some explanation as to how this solves the problem, or how this differs from the existing answers. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/22545702)

Comment: Upvoting because it was the simplest, fastest solution to a quick test I was doing.

Answer (score 0):

For WGL case described in the [answer by eugensk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/589232/3322435).

If you run into a nullptr error, make sure you are running {`wglGetProcAddress`} part code in an OpenGL Context.

i.e. after codes {`glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);`}.

See answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21771738).