# Cocoa OpenGL unlocked framerate

Tags: performance, macos, cocoa, opengl, frame-rate

I want to be able to run my game without a locked framerate (currently 60 fps). The only way that I have found to run the animation is with a NSTimer. Is there a way to have an unrestricted framerate in Cocoa. If so, a link or a code snippet would help greatly.

Comment: What's the point of drawing faster than the display can refresh? You're just wasting CPU cycles. If you use a `CVDisplayLink` you're guaranteed to be drawing as fast as the display will go.

Comment: @RobKeniger I'm doing this mainly to see how quickly one frame can be completed so that I can figure if I can integrate more complex and accurate calculations for things like collision detection and phong lighting. I can't really do this though because I have a locked framerate and can't tell how much more the CPU can handle per frame.

Comment: @Chase: Sure you can.  Just use a high precision timer to measure how much time is spent waiting for the next frame to begin.

Comment: @BenVoigt that actually makes a lot of sense. If you post that as an answer I can close this question. Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you really want to do this, you might need to use the [CGL](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGL_OpenGL/Reference/reference.html) interface. In a valid GL context, `CGLGetCurrentContext` returns an (opaque) context object. `CGLSetParameter` can be used to set a value for the `kCGLCPSwapInterval` parameter. A value of `(0)` disables waiting for vsync.

Answer (score 5):

This enabled me to get around ~700 frames per second on my MacBook Pro

- [Download Graphics Tools for Xcode - Late August 2014](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?q=graphics)
- Install or just mount **Graphic Tools**
- Open **Quartz Debug**
- Go to Tools -> Show Beam Sync Tools
- Select Disable Beam Synchronization

It is not permanent either, perfect for testing/benchmarking.

[Source](https://discussions.apple.com/message/2962693#discussion-2959446)

Comment: This still works with 10.9? I'll have to try that. Just setting the swap interval like described in the older answer did not work anymore for me.

Comment: Go to Tools -> Show Beam Sync Tools no longer exists in the latest tools, idea?

Comment: Hmm. Perhaps download an older/newer version of Graphic Tools? Specifically [Late August 2014](http://adcdownload.apple.com/Developer_Tools/graphics_tools_for_xcode__late_august_2014/graphicstools_late_august_2014.dmg)

Answer (score 0):

The Quartz debugger in Xcode 11 (version 4.2) moved this to:

Tools->Quartz Debug Settings->Enable Vertical Sync

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/24812414)

Comment: but it sure followed the thread above. Should I cut and paste the 5 year old answer or can we somehow add this add a comment?