# How to disable Vsync on mac os x 10.11 El Capitan

Tags: xcode, graphics, osx-elcapitan

There is a solution here: [How to disable vsync on macOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12345730/how-to-disable-vsync-on-mac-osx)

However This only works for 10.10 and older, and Xcode 6 and older.  It seems that the quartz debug that comes with Xcode 7 does not have options to turn of vysnc (beam sync).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I'm running a Mac Book pro 13' if that matters.

Comment: Is this a programming question or a user question?

Comment: I suppose its not exactly a programing questions.  Its more of a gernal developing question, use to trouble shoot graphics problems on a mac.  I'm thinking that this may be preventing refresh problems for how graphics draw on my screen.  But i could be way off base.

If there is a more appropriate place to post this question I'm more than happy to relocate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After YEARS looking for a workaround, this is what worked for me - I've added that piece of code at the start of my render loop and was finally have unsynchronize framerate:

```
#ifdef __APPLE__
GLint                       sync = 0;
CGLContextObj               ctx = CGLGetCurrentContext();

CGLSetParameter(ctx, kCGLCPSwapInterval, &sync);
#endif
```

Don't forget to include `<OpenGL/gl.h>`

It's not the nicest solution but it's actually the only one I found that work like a charm.

Comment: Confirmed working on macOS 10.14, but seems this is not working on macOS 10.15 and 11 anymore, I've tried `kCGLCPSwapInterval` /  `NSOpenGLCPSwapInterval` / `CVDisplayLink`

Comment: Found out on macOS 10.15 and 11, the actual drawing code including `flushBuffer()` must not be put in `func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect)`

Comment: @vk.edward.li so is there a solution for macOS 11?

Comment: @Slbox the above solution works, as long as you don't put the drawing code inside `func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect)` (if my memory serves me right)