# xlib / egl how to get VSync/swapInterval on eglSwapBuffers

Tags: linux, xlib, egl

I'm wondering how to properly enable vsync with `eglSwapBuffers` when using xlib. It seems that calls to `eglSwapInterval` are simply ignored.

I'm running both in a windowed and full-screen mode. Is it possible that it simply isn't supported in the windowed mode?  In this case, what is a good way to reduce the frequency at which I render (sleeping tends to cause errative behaviour as there is no guarantee when it awakes).

Answer (score 1):

Eventually I found this after a lot of googling:

http://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/mesa-commit/2010-May/021020.html

> egl: Implement EGL_NOK_swap_region
>
> This extension adds a new function which provides an alternative to
>   eglSwapBuffers. eglSwapBuffersRegionNOK accepts two new parameters in
>   addition to those in eglSwapBuffers. The new parameters consist of a
>   pointer to a list of 4-integer blocks defining rectangles (x, y,
>   width, height) and an integer specifying the number of rectangles in
>   the list.

And /usr/include/EGL/eglmesaext.h declares

```
EGLAPI EGLBoolean EGLAPIENTRY eglSwapBuffersRegionNOK(EGLDisplay dpy, EGLSurface surface, EGLint numRects, const EGLint* rects);
```

There's also some example usage here:

https://github.com/blazt/piglit/blob/master/tests/egl/egl-nok-swap-region.c

So I tried using it like this:

```
EGLint dirtyRect[4] = { 0, 0, 0, 0 };
PFNEGLSWAPBUFFERSREGIONNOK swap_buffers_region = (PFNEGLSWAPBUFFERSREGIONNOK)
    eglGetProcAddress("eglSwapBuffersRegionNOK");
```

and in my window resizing callback

```
dirtyRect[2] = windowWidth;
dirtyRect[3] = windowHeight;
```

and in my main loop

```
if (swap_buffers_region)
    swap_buffers_region(egl_dpy, egl_surf, 1, dirtyRect);
else
    eglSwapBuffers(egl_dpy, egl_surf);
```

It does seem smoother and slowed down the frame rate, but only down to the range of 180-200 FPS; so I still need to do a usleep between frames.  Maybe it only blocks swapping buffers during some short interval of critical GPU operations?  Or maybe I'm not doing it right.  Not sure.