# Trouble with vsync using glut in OpenGL

Tags: c++, windows, opengl, freeglut, vsync

I'm struggling desperately to get Vsync to work in my OpenGL application.  Here's the vital stats:

I'm using Windows, coding in C++ OpenGL and I'm using FreeGLUT for my OpenGL context (double buffering).  I'm aware that for the swap buffer to wait for vertical sync in Windows you are required to call wglSwapIntervalEXT().

My code does call this (as you'll see below), yet I am still getting vertical tearing.  The only way I've managed to stop it is by calling glFinish() which of course has a significant performance penalty associated with it.

The relevant parts of my main() function look like this:

```
//Initiating glut window
glutInit(&argc, argv);
glutInitDisplayMode (GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DEPTH);
glutInitWindowSize (initial_window_width, initial_window_height);
glutInitWindowPosition (100, 100);
int glut_window_hWnd = glutCreateWindow(window_title.c_str()); 

//Setting up swap intervals
PFNWGLSWAPINTERVALEXTPROC       wglSwapIntervalEXT = NULL;
PFNWGLGETSWAPINTERVALEXTPROC    wglGetSwapIntervalEXT = NULL;

if (WGLExtensionSupported("WGL_EXT_swap_control"))
{
// Extension is supported, init pointers.
wglSwapIntervalEXT = PFNWGLSWAPINTERVALEXTPROC)wglGetProcAddress("wglSwapIntervalEXT");

// this is another function from WGL_EXT_swap_control extension
wglGetSwapIntervalEXT = (PFNWGLGETSWAPINTERVALEXTPROC)wglGetProcAddress("wglGetSwapIntervalEXT");
}

wglSwapIntervalEXT (1)

init ();

glutMainLoop();    ///Starting the glut loop
return(0);
```

I should point out that the return from the wglInitSwapControlARB function is true, so the extension is supported.

Comment: Have you checked your display driver settings? They all have an option to override application-preferences for things like MSAA, VSYNC, texture filtering, etc. If it is set to explicitly disable VSYNC then there's nothing you can do except for change the driver setting to respect application preferences. You may have forced adaptive VSYNC on in the preferences not knowing exactly how that worked... it allows the screen to tear at framerates < `RefreshHz` but keeps the application from drawing more than `RefreshHz` FPS... it cuts down on power consumption and tearing at high framerates.

Comment: Adaptive VSYNC can also be requested at the application level, if your implementation supports `WGL_EXT_swap_control_tear`. You can request it by passing **-1** to `wglSwapIntervalEXT (...)`. On the right hardware in Windows Vista/7/8 you do not even need VSYNC while drawing in windowed mode. On all of my AMD hardware I can draw at > 12,000 FPS without any tearing in windowed mode, but in fullscreen mode VSYNC is essential.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  I have tried wflSwapIntervalEXT(-1) but I still get tearing, besides I would like to run in full screen mode.  Regarding the first comment, I checked my driver settings, it was set to application preference, but even when I forced VSYNC to be on, i'm still getting tearing.  :(

Comment: Do any other OpenGL applications on your system work with VSYNC? I am reluctant to blame GLUT for this, because I do not think it even knows about swap intervals (the original GLUT framework did not), but it may be setting the value of `wglSwapIntervalEXT (...)` before it does a buffer swap.

Comment: Also, when you call `wglSwapIntervalEXT (...)`, does it return `FALSE`? I think GLUT may not have your GL context active in the calling thread when you try to make this call.

Comment: Thanks for your time Andon, yes it does return true.  I also thought it might be the OpenGL context not being active through its initiation via freeGLUT.  Do you know a way of forcing the context to be active just prior to the wglSwapIntervalEXT?  Thanks again, I appreciate it very much.

Comment: My guess: You disables V-Sync in the driver settings in a way that it overrides all application settings. I'd check that first before messing with the swap interval. In all drivers you can set to V-Sync by default which effectively sets the swap interval to 1 as default value.

Comment: Unfortunately note datenwold, vsync may be set to on or application defined in the driver (via the control panel) and neither method stops the tearing, it's very frustrating!

Comment: I've just spent a couple of hours re-writing my code to use a different API to freeGLUT, I am now using GLFW and using glfwSwapInterval(1) or even glfwSwapInterval(1000) I still get tearing.  I have confirmed the functions are returning true as well, and my driver setting is set to use VSYNC.  I am using a laptop though, not sure if that will mean anything!?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok - between the great help I've received here, and my own hours of research and messing around with it I've discovered a few things, including a solution that works for me (in case others come across this problem).

Firstly, I was using freeGLUT, I converted my code to GLFW and the result was the same, so this was NOT an API issue, don't waste your time like I did!

In my program at least, using wglSwapIntervalEXT(1) DOES NOT stop vertical tearing, and this was what led to it being such a headache to solve.

With my NVIDIA driver set to VSYNC = ON I was still getting tearing (because this is equivalent to SwapInterval(1) which doesn't help) - but it was set correctly, the driver was doing what it should have been I just didn't know it because I was still getting tearing.

So I set my NVIDIA driver to VSYNC = 'Application preference' and used wglSwapIntervalEXT(60) instead of 1 which I had always been using, and found that this was actually working because it was giving me a refresh rate of about 1Hz.

I don't know why wglSwapIntervalEXT(1) doesn't Vsync my screen, but wglSwapIntervalEXT(2) has the desired effect, though obviously I'm now rendering every other frame which is inefficient.

I found that with VSYNC disabled glFinish DOES NOT help with tearing, but with it enabled it does (If anyone can explain why that would be great).

So in summary, with wglSwapIntervalEXT(1) set and glFinish() enabled I no longer have tearing, but I don't understand still why.

Here's some performance stats in my app (deliberately loaded to have FPS's below 60):

- wglSwapIntervalEXT(0) = Tearing = 58 FPS
- wglSwapIntervalEXT(1) = Tearing = 58 FPS
- wglSwapIntervalEXT(2) = No tearing = 30 FPS
- wglSwapIntervalEXT(1) + glFinish = No Tearing = 52 FPS

I hope this helps someone in the future.  Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

i am also having problem with vsync and freeglut.
previously i used glut, and i was able to selectivly enable vsync for multiple GLUT-windows.

Now with freeglut, it seems like that the wglSwapIntervalEXT() has no effect.
What has effect is the global vsync option in the NVIDIA control panel. If I enable the vsync there, i have vsync in both of my freeglut windows, and if i disable i dont have. It does not matter what i set specificly for my application (in the nvidia control panel).
Also this confirms what i observe:

```
if(wglSwapIntervalEXT(0)) 
printf("VSYNC set\n");
int swap=wglGetSwapIntervalEXT();
printf("Control window vsync: %i\n",swap);
```

the value of swap is always the value that is set in the NVIDIA control panel.
Does not matter what is want to set with wglSwapIntervalEXT().

Otherwise here you can read what the GLFinish() is good for:
http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Swap_Interval

I use it because i need to know when my monitor is updated, so i can synchronously execute tasks after that (capture with a camera something).

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is quite old, but I'll answer anyway, more as a reminder to myself if I encounter this issue again than anything.
When setting up the Pixel Format for your "presenting" context (the one that'll be responsible for calling `SwapBuffers`), you HAVE to use `WGL_DOUBLE_BUFFER_ARB` as an attribute. Otherwise `SwapBuffers` will just copy the current back buffer to the window buffer and ignore the swap interval (as there is no swap occuring)

Answer (score -1):

As described in this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589064/how-to-enable-vertical-sync-in-opengl), no "true" VSync exists. Using GLFinish is the correct approach. This will cause your Card to finish processing everything it has been sent before continuing and rendering the next frame.

You should keep track of your FPS and the time to render a frame, you might find GLFinish is simply exposing another bottleneck in your code.

Comment: I maybe wrong but I was under the impression that GLFinish would introduce a bottleneck because it forces a sync between the CPU and GPU, I'm sure I've read that somewhere?  Also, in that post you suggested (which I had already read) it was suggested that the person should use the Swap Interval approach which is what I've done, but it isn't working.

Comment: Have you thought about throttling the rendering thread yourself?

Comment: Yes I've thought about it.  But from what I've read I shouldn't have to, which is why I'm hoping someone out there knows why the swap interval approach is compiling and running but not doing anything

Comment: framerate throttling is a really bad idea. And V-Sync is perfectly possible in OpenGL. The basic principle is that after a SwapBuffers call the next function call that would alter the contents of the back buffer is hold back until the buffer swap actually happened. So either the OpenGL command queue fills up until calls block. Anyhow with V-Sync enabled the framerate will be capped to the V-Sync rate.