# Tearing with cocos2d-x on PC at native resolution, fullscreen, 60fps

Tags: opengl, cocos2d-x, vsync

I'm programming a game with cocos2d-x for Windows, Linux and MacOS (for the moment I develop and test on Windows 10). I already have a system to change settings (either fullscreen or windowed with different resolutions but always a ratio of 16:9).

I've implemented a prototype of my levels system, with only a few sprites and the ability to move horizontally. In windowed mode everything is ok, but in fullscreen mode at native resolution I experience some tearing, though the resolution is set to 60 fps, on a 60 Hz screen (and the fps counter actually displays 60).

When investigating this issue, I've read on the thread [OpenGL tearing with fullscreen native resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30293074/opengl-tearing-with-fullscreen-native-resolution) that this may be due to bypassing the DWM compositor in fullscreen native resolution, which is otherwise doing some kind of vsync.

I would like to force vsync but I've not found any function neither in class `cocos2d::Director` nor `cocos2d::GLView` to do this, and with cocos2d-x I can't do this on a low-level (never using OpenGL directly).

Any idea of how to remove tearing / force vsync?