# How do I display an image for a few miliseconds correctly?

Tags: performance, time, hardware, image-rendering

I want to be able to display and close an image within a few miliseonds.

I generally understand how to do this for a few seconds, but how can I achieve accurate milisecond rendering?

What is the approach to ensure that I can be certain an image has only been open for 10 miliseconds or even 5 milisecond and that my monitor has indeed displayed this image (assuming I have for example a 240hz monitor).

From my limited understanding of a monitors refresh rate, a 240hz monitor may refresh the display 240 times a second which is around every 4 miliseconds. If I want to display something for 5 miliseconds, it's possible that more than half that time my monitor hasn't really been refreshing (therefore not displaying). Under that logic is it correct that I would need to display the image for around 4 or 8 miliseconds? Is there a way to synchronize my displays refresh rate with the output of my program?

I'm planning to do this in c++ although the language isn't too critical provided the problem can be solved. I haven't managed to find any sources on how to approach this sort of problem. Is there any direction to a solution for this sort of problem?

Comment: The operating system you are running might be critical to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sync'ing is known as V-sync (Vertical Sync), since displays are typically oriented in *horizontal* lines. That means an entire screen is shown after the last line is drawn, just before the next line at the top of the screen will be drawn. I.e. the V-sync event is the vertical wrap-around.

You need a game-oriented API like DirectX or [OpenGL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589064/how-to-enable-vertical-sync-in-opengl)